# Crawling Website for First Column in Python

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am using Python to crawl the website using following code

```
def ReadContent(url):
    html = GetWebPageContent(url)

    parser = ReadingContentParser(strict=False)
    parser.feed(html)

    if not parser.text_appear:
        print("Ipad Mini is on sale!")
        Alert()
    else:
        print("Ipad Mini is not available!")

ReadContent(URL_TO_CHECK)
```

Now I want to check whether an IPhone Gold (16GB) is "Available" or Selling Fast" at [here](http://info.singtel.com/personal/phones-plans/mobile/ios/iphone5s?type=2&device=1312&colour=gold#stock-availability), how should I check that? The problem is I am not sure how to get only the status of **Gold (16GB)** but not **Gold (32GB)** or **Gold (64GB)**, since they are all in a big table. How should I get it works? Should i use some other library like Scrapy and so on?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [lxml with xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method):

```
from lxml import html
url = "http://info.singtel.com/personal/phones-plans/mobile/ios/iphone5s?type=2&device=1312&colour=gold#stock-availability"
doc = html.parse(url)
for tr in doc.xpath('//div[@class="available-stock"]//tr'):
    if tr.xpath('td'):
        print tr.xpath('td[1]')[0].text.strip(), 
              tr.xpath('td[2]/strong')[0].text == 'Sold Out'
```

output:

```
City Square Mall True
ION Orchard True
Plaza Singapura True
Raffles City True
United Square True
...
```

Comment: Let me do that for you! Gotta love a @Guy like that.